# APT returns error asking me to set a variable that already exists

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, ubuntu, apt

Anytime I run an APT command (for example `sudo apt update`) it fetches a couple repositories, and then returns a python error like follows:

```
Could not find platform independent libraries <prefix>
Consider setting $PYTHONHOME to <prefix>[:<exec_prefix>]
Python path configuration:
  PYTHONHOME = (not set)
  PYTHONPATH = (not set)
  program name = '/usr/bin/python3'
  isolated = 0
  environment = 1
  user site = 1
  import site = 1
  sys._base_executable = '/usr/bin/python3'
  sys.base_prefix = '/usr/local'
  sys.base_exec_prefix = '/usr'
  sys.platlibdir = 'lib'
  sys.executable = '/usr/bin/python3'
  sys.prefix = '/usr/local'
  sys.exec_prefix = '/usr'
  sys.path = [
    '/usr/local/lib/python310.zip',
    '/usr/local/lib/python3.10',
    '/usr/lib/python3.10/lib-dynload',
  ]
Fatal Python error: init_fs_encoding: failed to get the Python codec of the filesystem encoding
Python runtime state: core initialized
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'encodings'

Current thread 0x00007fcb30a512c0 (most recent call first):
  <no Python frame>
Reading package lists... Done
E: Problem executing scripts APT::Update::Post-Invoke-Success 'if /usr/bin/test -w /var/lib/command-not-found/ -a -e /usr/lib/cnf-update-db; then /usr/lib/cnf-update-db > /dev/null; fi'
E: Sub-process returned an error code
```

I have set the `$PYTHONHOME` and `$PYTHONPATH` variables to my python install. So what is the problem here?

Comment: This is becoming a security issue, as I can't update any of my packages, so I'd really appreciate an answer

Comment: Year 2021 Ubuntu's: The default python3 is v3.9.4 or earlier. All Ubuntu admin tools (like apt) depend on the system version of python. Solution: Either revert to default ...... or reinstall the OS. ...... ( Installed alien versions must be in a hidden PATH / a hidden environment.)